# Getting input text search auto filled using jquery & jsp not working

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

I have below web page it shows I have created one table & added AddRow & remove row functions using jquery. I am calling JSP file through AJAX call for auto search.
But it seems working for only first row of table & when m searching in newly added row suggestions are showing in first row only.

Below is screenshot
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Denotes total number of rows
  var rowIdx = 0;

  // jQuery button click event to add a row
  $('#addBtn').on('click', function() {

    // Adding a row inside the tbody.
    $('#tbody').append(`
      <tr id="R${++rowIdx}">
         <td class="row-index text-center">
           <p>Row ${rowIdx}</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cb"><input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="inputString" name="inputString" />
                     <div id="showList">
                         <ul class="list-group"></ul>
                     </div>
         </td>
              <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="debit"   class="form-control">
        </td>
              <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="credit"class="form-control">
        </td>
              <td>
          <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>`);
  });

  /*$("#tbody").on("keyup"," input[name^=inputString]", function(){
      $("tbody tr").each(function () {
        var search = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(rowIdx) input").val();
        
        if(search !='' && search !=null) {
          $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ledgers.jsp',
            data:'key='+search,
            success:function(data){
              $('#showList').html(data);
            }
          });
        }
        else {
          $('#showList').html('');
        }
      });
    });*/

  $("#tbody").on("keyup", " input[name^=inputString]", function() {
    $("tbody tr").each(function() {
      var search = $(this).closest('tr').find("input").val();
      
      if (search != '' && search != null) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ledgers.jsp',
          data: 'key=' + search,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#showList').html(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#showList').html('');
      }
    });
  });

  $("#tbody").on("click", "li", function() {
    $('#inputString').val($(this).text());
    $('#showList').html('');
  });
  
  // jQuery button click event to remove a row.
  $('#tbody').on('click', '.remove', function() {

    // Getting all the rows next to the row
    // containing the clicked button
    var child = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll();

    // Iterating across all the rows 
    // obtained to change the index
    child.each(function() {

      // Getting <tr> id.
      var id = $(this).attr('id');

      // Getting the <p> inside the .row-index class.
      var idx = $(this).children('.row-index').children('p');

      // Gets the row number from <tr> id.
      var dig = parseInt(id.substring(1));

      // Modifying row index.
      idx.html(`Row ${dig - 1}`);

      // Modifying row id.
      $(this).attr('id', `R${dig - 1}`);
    });

    // Removing the current row.
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    // Decreasing total number of rows by 1.
    rowIdx--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group required col-md-8">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="table_field">
    <thead>
      <tr id="r1">
        <th>Row No</th>
        <th>Ledger Name</th>
        <th>Debit</th>
        <th>Credit</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Add or Remove</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody>
    
    <tr>
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="add" id="addBtn" value="Add">
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <center>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
  </center>
</div>
```

can anybody suggest me whats wrong with above code.

Run auto search for every table row TD input field

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxPPy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the keyup function() with below code:

```
$("#tbody").on("keyup", "input[name^=inputString]", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("tbody tr").each(function() {
      var search = $(this).closest('tr').find("input").val();
      
      if (search != '' && search != null) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ledgers.jsp',
          data: 'key=' + search,
          success: function(data) {
            $this.next('#showList').html(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#showList').html('');
      }
    });
  });
```

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Thanks.

Comment: This is working fine bro .. it is completing auto search for every row. But now for newly added rows when I click on that it is not appending to that input
this is my li on click function:
$(document).on('click','li',function(){
      $('#inputString').val($(this).text());
      $('#showList').html('');
     });

Comment: Great. I am glad that it's work. I love jQuery

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: `$("#tbody").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).closest('input').val($(this).text());
    $('#showList').html('');
  });`

Comment: where should I keep this in keyup function or outside keyup function?

Comment: Outside keyup function

Comment: nope bro it is not working. Please check screenshot I am adding into questions 
Please check this -  enter image description here

Comment: it is updating data on first row itself even when m selecting it on any other row